# How to get Text written after "," in MultiAutoCompleteTextView?

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I am developing an application that uses MultiAutoCompleteTextView for showing hints in the drop down list.In this application I retrieve the value written in the MultiAutoCompleteTextView by using

```
multitextview.getText();
```

and then query this value to server to recieve JSON response which is shown as suggestions in the drop down list.

If a user types Mu and then Selects music from the list and  then types box for another suggestion the content in the MultiAutoCompleteTextView becomes Music,box and now the value for querying to the server is Music,box instead of this I want to select only box.

My question is how to retrieve text written after "," in MultiAutoCompleteTextView?
Can this be achieved using  `getText()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this issue

```
String intermediate_text=multitextview.getText().toString();
String final_string=intermediate_text.substring(intermediate_text.lastIndexOf(",")+1);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there are several ways to get around this. One way to do it would be:

```
String textToQuerryServer = null;
    String str = multitextview.getText().toString(); // i.e "music, box" or "any, thing, you , want";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*,\\s*(.*)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);

    if (m.find()) {
        textToQuerryServer = m.group(1);
        System.out.println("Pattern found: "+ textToQuerryServer);
    }else {
        textToQuerryServer = str;
        System.out.println("No pattern: "+ textToQuerryServer);
    }
```

Comment: I think you can not put String str=multitextview.getText(); it will give Type mismatch: cannot convert from Editable to String +1 for the approach.